# Disable Aloha Editor sidebar

Tags: javascript, aloha-editor

I want to disable the [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/) sidebar. I've seen the following code in various places, which doesn't work for me:

```
Aloha.settings = {
  sidebar: { disabled: true }
};
```

If I add it *after* the call to `aloha()`, nothing happens and the sidebar remains. If I add it *before* I call `aloha()` on elements, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContents' of undefined
```

All of this is taking place in `Aloha.ready` and isn't fixed if I move the code above my call to `Aloha.ready`.

If it's helpful, here are the files I'm loading in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/require.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/aloha.js" data-aloha-plugins="common/ui, common/format, common/list, common/link, common/highlighteditables, common/horizontalruler, common/undo, common/paste"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/css/aloha.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

(I'm currently adding [some CSS](http://pastebin.com/BFFZkDsL), which feels wrong. I'd prefer a nicer solution.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run JS for settings **before** calling `aloha.js`:

```
<script>
Aloha = {};
Aloha.settings = { sidebar: { disabled: true } };
</script>
<script src="aloha/lib/vendor/require.js"></script>
<script src="aloha/lib/aloha.js"></script>
```